How to make pnpm show the full dependencies tree
I am using pnpm v8.15.1 to show the project dependencies tree, the command look like this:
pnpm ls lodash --depth=Infinity

the output look like this:
> pnpm ls lodash --depth=Infinity
Legend: production dependency, optional only, dev only

texhub-web@0.1.0 /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/texhub-web

dependencies:
@testing-library/jest-dom 5.17.0
└── lodash 4.17.21
lodash 4.17.21
rd-component 0.1.156
├─┬ storybook 7.6.17
│ └─┬ @storybook/cli 7.6.17
│   ├─┬ @storybook/codemod 7.6.17
│   │ └── lodash 4.17.21
│   └─┬ @storybook/core-server 7.6.17
│     ├─┬ @storybook/preview-api 7.6.17
│     │ └── lodash 4.17.21
│     └── lodash 4.17.21
└─┬ vite-plugin-dts 2.3.0
  └─┬ @microsoft/api-extractor 7.43.0
    └── lodash 4.17.21
rdjs-wheel 0.0.29
├─┬ storybook 7.6.17
│ └─┬ @storybook/cli 7.6.17
│   ├─┬ @storybook/codemod 7.6.17
│   │ └── lodash 4.17.21
│   └─┬ @storybook/core-server 7.6.17
│     ├─┬ @storybook/preview-api 7.6.17
│     │ └── lodash 4.17.21
│     └── lodash 4.17.21
└─┬ vite-plugin-dts 2.3.0
  └─┬ @microsoft/api-extractor 7.43.0
    └── lodash 4.17.21

when I use the npm npm@9.6.7 to show the dependencies tree, the output shows more output than pnpm. Which one is the better way to guide me the dependencies analysis? the npm shows like this:
> npm ls lodash --depth=20
npm info using npm@9.6.7
npm info using node@v16.14.2
npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! invalid: lodash@4.17.21 /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/texhub-web/node_modules/.pnpm/node_modules/lodash
texhub-web@0.1.0 /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/texhub-web
├─┬ @ant-design/icons@5.3.5 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/@ant-design+icons@5.3.5_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/@ant-design/icons
│ ├─┬ @ant-design/icons-svg@4.4.2 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/@ant-design+icons-svg@4.4.2/node_modules/@ant-design/icons-svg
│ │ └─┬ svgo@1.3.2 invalid: "^3.0.2" from node_modules/.pnpm/@svgr+core@8.1.0_typescript@4.9.5/node_modules/@svgr/core -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/svgo@1.3.2/node_modules/svgo
│ │   ├─┬ css-select@2.1.0 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/css-select@2.1.0/node_modules/css-select
│ │   │ └─┬ domutils@1.7.0 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/domutils@1.7.0/node_modules/domutils
│ │   │   └─┬ dom-serializer@0.2.2 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/dom-serializer@0.2.2/node_modules/dom-serializer
│ │   │     └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped invalid: "^2.4.2" from node_modules/.pnpm/ansi-html-community@0.0.8/node_modules/ansi-html-community, "^2.4.2" from node_modules/.pnpm/ansi-html-community@0.0.8/node_modules/ansi-html-community, "~3.10.1" from node_modules/.pnpm/esprima@4.0.1/node_modules/esprima, "~3.10.1" from node_modules/.pnpm/esprima@4.0.1/node_modules/esprima, "~3.10.1" from node_modules/.pnpm/esprima@4.0.1/node_modules/esprima -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/lodash@4.17.21/node_modules/lodash
│ │   └─┬ js-yaml@3.14.1 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/js-yaml@3.14.1/node_modules/js-yaml
│ │     └─┬ esprima@4.0.1 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/esprima@4.0.1/node_modules/esprima
│ │       └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped invalid: "^2.4.2" from node_modules/.pnpm/ansi-html-community@0.0.8/node_modules/ansi-html-community, "^2.4.2" from node_modules/.pnpm/ansi-html-community@0.0.8/node_modules/ansi-html-community, "~3.10.1" from node_modules/.pnpm/esprima@4.0.1/node_modules/esprima, "~3.10.1" from node_modules/.pnpm/esprima@4.0.1/node_modules/esprima, "~3.10.1" from node_modules/.pnpm/esprima@4.0.1/node_modules/esprima -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/lodash@4.17.21/node_modules/lodash
│ ├─┬ @swc/core@1.4.11 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/@swc+core@1.4.11/node_modules/@swc/core
│ │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/lodash@4.17.21/node_modules/lodash
│ ├─┬ eslint@8.57.0 invalid: "^7.31.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/@eslint+eslintrc@2.1.4/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc, "^6.7.2" from node_modules/.pnpm/@fortawesome+react-fontawesome@0.2.0_@fortawesome+fontawesome-svg-core@6.5.1_react@18.2.0/node_modules/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome, "^7.25.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/@reduxjs+toolkit@1.9.5_react-redux@8.1.3_react@18.2.0/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit, "~8.7.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/@rushstack+eslint-patch@1.10.1/node_modules/@rushstack/eslint-patch, "^4.19.1" from node_modules/.pnpm/dayjs@1.11.10/node_modules/dayjs, "8.53.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/i18next@23.10.1/node_modules/i18next, "^7.12.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/react-redux@8.1.3_@types+react-dom@18.2.23_@types+react@18.2.73_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_redux@4.2.1/node_modules/react-redux, "^7.7.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/react-syntax-highlighter@15.5.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-syntax-highlighter, "^3.19.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/redux-logger@3.0.6/node_modules/redux-logger, "^7.32.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/redux-thunk@2.4.2_redux@4.2.1/node_modules/redux-thunk, "^6.8.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/redux@4.2.1/node_modules/redux, "8.21.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/uuid@9.0.1/node_modules/uuid, "^7.1.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/@ant-design+colors@7.0.2/node_modules/@ant-design/colors, "^7.16.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/@ant-design+icons-svg@4.4.2/node_modules/@ant-design/icons-svg -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/eslint@8.57.0/node_modules/eslint
│ │ ├─┬ @nodelib/fs.walk@1.2.8 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/@nodelib+fs.walk@1.2.8/node_modules/@nodelib/fs.walk
│ │ │ └─┬ fastq@1.17.1 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/fastq@1.17.1/node_modules/fastq
│ │ │   └─┬ neo-async@2.6.2 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/neo-async@2.6.2/node_modules/neo-async
│ │ │     └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped invalid: "^2.4.2" from node_modules/.pnpm/ansi-html-community@0.0.8/node_modules/ansi-html-community, "^2.4.2" from node_modules/.pnpm/ansi-html-community@0.0.8/node_modules/ansi-html-community, "~3.10.1" from node_modules/.pnpm/esprima@4.0.1/node_modules/esprima, "~3.10.1" from node_modules/.pnpm/esprima@4.0.1/node_modules/esprima, "~3.10.1" from node_modules/.pnpm/esprima@4.0.1/node_modules/esprima -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/lodash@4.17.21/node_modules/lodash
│ │ ├─┬ optionator@0.9.3 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/optionator@0.9.3/node_modules/optionator
│ │ │ └─┬ fast-levenshtein@2.0.6 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/fast-levenshtein@2.0.6/node_modules/fast-levenshtein
│ │ │   └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped invalid: "^2.4.2" from node_modules/.pnpm/ansi-html-community@0.0.8/node_modules/ansi-html-community, "^2.4.2" from node_modules/.pnpm/ansi-html-community@0.0.8/node_modules/ansi-html-community -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/lodash@4.17.21/node_modules/lodash
│ │ └─┬ recast@0.23.6 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/recast@0.23.6/node_modules/recast
│ │   └─┬ esprima@4.0.1 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/esprima@4.0.1/node_modules/esprima
│ │     └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped invalid: "^2.4.2" from node_modules/.pnpm/ansi-html-community@0.0.8/node_modules/ansi-html-community, "^2.4.2" from node_modules/.pnpm/ansi-html-community@0.0.8/node_modules/ansi-html-community, "~3.10.1" from node_modules/.pnpm/esprima@4.0.1/node_modules/esprima -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/lodash@4.17.21/node_modules/lodash
│ ├── lodash@4.17.21 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/lodash@4.17.21/node_modules/lodash
│ └─┬ ts-node@10.9.2 invalid: "^8.0.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/@ant-design+icons@5.3.5_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/@ant-design/icons, "10.9.1" from node_modules/.pnpm/rd-lang-tex@0.0.6/node_modules/rd-lang-tex, "10.9.1" from node_modules/.pnpm/rd-lezer-tex@0.0.3/node_modules/rd-lezer-tex, "^8.6.2" from node_modules/.pnpm/@ant-design+icons-svg@4.4.2/node_modules/@ant-design/icons-svg -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/ts-node@10.9.2_@types+node@16.18.91_typescript@4.9.5/node_modules/ts-node
│   ├─┬ @cspotcode/source-map-support@0.8.1 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/@cspotcode+source-map-support@0.8.1/node_modules/@cspotcode/source-map-support
│   │ └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/lodash@4.17.21/node_modules/lodash
│   └── lodash@4.17.21 deduped -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/lodash@4.17.21/node_modules/lodash
├─┬ @eslint-community/regexpp@4.10.0 extraneous -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/@eslint-community+regexpp@4.10.0/node_modules/@eslint-community/regexpp
│ └─┬ jsdom@16.7.0 invalid: "^19.0.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/@eslint-community+regexpp@4.10.0/node_modules/@eslint-community/regexpp, "^24.0.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/antd@5.15.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/antd, "^20.0.3" from node_modules/.pnpm/jspreadsheet-ce@4.13.4/node_modules/jspreadsheet-ce, "^23.0.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/rc-table@7.40.0_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/rc-table, "19.0.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/rdjs-wheel@0.0.29_@types+node@16.18.91_esbuild@0.18.20_rollup@4.13.2_ts-node@10.9.2_typescrip_5mjgwci46ytskkexebseip4q2y/node_modules/rdjs-wheel, "^24.0.0" from node_modules/.pnpm/react-pdf@7.7.1_@types+react@18.2.73_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-pdf -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/jsdom@16.7.0/node_modules/jsdom
│   ├─┬ data-urls@2.0.0 -> ./node_modules/.pnpm/data-urls@2.0.0/node_modules/data-urls

why the pnpm and npm result are different? Am I missing something?

Just a note, don't ask "Is it possible to xxx" because the answer to that is yes or no - which doesn't help you at all. Instead ask "How to accomplish xxx" or even "xxx" itself. The more concise the title the easier it is for people to see if they can assist.
